# Is there a name for the way Excel scrolls through cells?

Tags: gui-design

I have noticed that while scrolling horizontally in Excel, it jumps to the start of the next cell without stopping in the middle of a cell. Is there a name for this type of scroll behavior?

Comment: Don't know! Even i'm curious about this. All MS Office releases after 2010 has really grabbed my attention when it came to UI.... !

Comment: How does stopping in the middle of a cell happens (normally)? Do you have video of this kind of behaviour?

Comment: I mean, when contrasted with grids or tables on the web, Excel skips the cell content if scroll stops in the middle of a cell and it snaps to the start of next cell.

Comment: You said it ! It's scroll-snapping :)

Comment: @Brice, that's it! Also there seems to be a CSS property for it now! Funny how you learn new things! :)

Comment: @Brice -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @Jasper Should I post as an answer ?

Answer (score 3):

As Brice mentioned in the comments, this is typically referred to as "Scroll Snapping."

There is a CSS property that is used for this type of scrolling:

- [W3C: CSS Scroll Snap](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-scroll-snap-1/)
- [MDN: CSS Scroll Snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap)